# Polynomial acting on Direct sums of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, diagonalization, direct-sum, block-matrices

1. (direct sum) If matrix $M$ is a direct sum, where $M=A_1⊕A_2⊕...⊕A_n$, is $p(M)=p(A_1)⊕p(A_2)⊕...⊕p(A_n)$, for any polynomial $p$?
2. (soft question) If property $P$ holds for **diagonal matrices**, then $P$ also holds for direct sums of matrices right?

Comment: Are all your matrices square matrices?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I think I understand what you mean: For any such block diagonal matrix $M$ in Q2, if some $A_i$ is not square then $p(A_i)$ would often be not well-defined (as long as $p$ involves some matrix powers), right? So the statement in 2 only holds for direct sums (ie. the case in Q1).

Comment: Yes, $p(A_i)$ is not defined for non-square matrices.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net But 1 is still true right? Applying polynomial p to a direct sum is the direct sum of $p(A_i)$.

Comment: For sure. This is an immediate consequence of block matrix product.